# array de arrays simples para json_encode

Tags: php, json

Preciso criar um documento json, com a seguinte estrutura:

```
[
{
    "Name": "Lacy",
    "Email": "ipsum@Quisqueac.net"
},
{
    "Name": "Chancellor",
    "Email": "neque.venenatis.lacus@neque.com"
}]
```

Atualmente, tenho o seguinte array:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'nome' => string 'Lacy' (length=35)
      'email' => string 'ipsum@Quisqueac.net' (length=20)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'nome' => string 'Chancellor' (length=25)
      'email' => string 'neque.venenatis.lacus@neque.com' (length=25)
```

E para tentar transforma-lo no resultado que pretendo, tenho o seguinte código:

```
$arrayClientes = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($clientes); $i++){
    array_push($arrayClientes, array("Nome"=>$clientes[$i]['nome'], "Email" => $clientes[$i]['email']));
}

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($arrayClientes);
echo '<pre>';
```

Desta forma, ele não faz o `echo` do `$arrayClientes`.

Como e que poderei criar um Json array como aqueles?

Comment: Já resolvi. O problema não estava no array, mas sim nos dados que recebia.
Tive de fazer utf8_encode ao nome que vinha no array.

Answer (score 2):

Assim também resolve:

```
$arrayClientes = array();

if (count($clientes))    
    foreach ($clientes as $cliente) {
        $arrayClientes[] = array(
                         "Name"  => $cliente['nome'],
                         "Email" => $cliente['email']
        );
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    echo json_encode($arrayClientes);
    echo '<pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja isso que você precisa, só adaptar um pouco:

```
$array = [
    0 => ['id' => 1, 'nome' => 'teste', 'email' => 'email'],
    1 => ['id' => 2, 'nome' => 'teste2', 'email' => 'email2'],
    2 => ['id' => 3, 'nome' => 'teste3', 'email' => 'email3']
];
var_dump($array); //teste

//Percorre todo o array, passando ele mesmo por referência para a função e removendo seu índice 'id'. 
//Assim permanecendo somente o que você precisa;
array_filter($array, function(&$array) {
    unset($array['id']);
});
var_dump($array); //teste

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Boas Rafael, o teu código funciona. O problema que estou a ter agora e com os parêntesis.. como converto o meu array para parêntesis retos ? porque o meu array vem de uma query aql

Comment: Em qual lugar exatamente acontece esse problema?

Comment: No SQL, você está recebendo seus dados como objeto? Como Array? @user3587262

Comment: Sim, o array que apresento e o que recebo

Comment: @user3587262, bom vi agora que que você já resolveu...